# when I created border on css and I put the link into that border but it's over border

Tags: html, css, border

I created class border for a link and put the link into that border. Then when I see by responsive device link is over length form that border while I try to keep sentence into border it has no problem.
How can I resolve it?

My CSS:

```
.border { 
    border: 1px solid #cc0000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Put it in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/).

Comment: Can show us the class names and html

Answer (score 0):

You probably used an element with `display: block` as a host of your `.border` class:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

`<div>`'s default `display` value is `block`, hence full width.

What you need is using an element with `display: inline`:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="border">
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</span>
```

Or, simply add `display: inline` to your `.border` styles:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline; /* <---- */
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```